# Am I using the eclipse debugger wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting a little frustrated. I am using jUnit and playing with a small sample size first to see if my algorithm sorts properly. It works! However, when I tried a large sample size, I get an error saying Array is out of bounds. I usually step through the recursion process, but with a huge sample size, it's just intolerable. Is there a way to actually get the debugger to stop at the state that causes the error so I can analyze and see what's wrong?

Comment: I guess you need exception break points.  
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471425/how-do-i-setup-eclipse-to-stop-on-the-line-an-exception-occured

Comment: I gave that shot, but I think I am doing it wrong. Right now, I am just using a catch and try and then printing out values on the exceptions. Could you give an example please?

Comment: I use intellij. Not easy to get you a working example on eclipse.

Comment: In Eclipse, go to the Breakpoints tab in the debugger, then look for a button to the right with a blue "J" and yellow exclamation mark (!). Clicking that will bring up a list of exceptions on which to break.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to preferences-> java-> debug and check "open popup when suspended on exception".